# How to install a python library for an Azure webjob?

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to create an Azure webjob that runs a python script which uses pyodbc.
The Azure compiler does not recognize pyodbc.
How do I install it or reference it in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by installing a python extension and running the script with the extension.  https://prmadi.com/running-python-webjob-on-azure-app-services-using-non-default-python-version/

Answer (score 1):

Get the working PyODBC first. To use PyODBC you should compile it in its 32bits version. Or install Python 2.7 or 3.4 (32-Bit) and type the command "pip install pyodbc"

To use it in Azure WebJob, put the PyODBC.pyd file in the root directory of your job and it should work.

Comment: I still get the error. Have also tried with the 64 bit.